# Kernel does not exist on the Jupyter. Please select another kernel. -DataSpell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, jupyter-irkernel, dataspell

I created one environment called 'xy'.
When I run jupyter notebook locally, it is working.
But when I try to run the same code in the same env, just in DataSpell, I'm getting the error "Kernel does not exist on the Jupyter. Please select another kernel."
I just run code, and nothing happens.

I tried to reinstall jupyter and I was getting the same error.